# define prototype of constructor property

Tags: javascript, prototype

Is something like this possible?

```
function Sleep(date) {
    this.Date = date || null;
    this.TimeWakeUp =
    this.PercAwake =
    this.MoodAfterAwake =
    this.Naps =
    this.TimeToBed =
    this.MoodToBed =
    null;
}

Object.defineProperty(Sleep, 'MoodAfterAwake', {
    __proto__: {
        options: [
            "bla",
            "bla",
            "bla",
            "bla"
        ]
    }
});
```

Basically I want a property on the Sleep constructor to inherit from a prototype, so even if Sleep.MoodAfterAwake is null or undefined I can still access Sleep.MoodAfterAwake.options.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

As JavaScript says: you can access any property of null/undefined. So this is not possible. Additionally you can check what actually null is at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null

Answer (score 0):

do you mean something like this

```
function Sleep(date) {
    this.Date = date || null;
    this.TimeWakeUp =
    this.PercAwake =
    this.MoodAfterAwake =
    this.Naps =
    this.TimeToBed =
    this.MoodToBed =
    null;
}

Sleep.prototype.moodAfterAwake = ["bla","bla","bla"]
```

Then you can access it like

```
var a = new Sleep()
a.moodAfterAwake[3];
```

or if you want to attach a property to Sleep function then no need for prototype. Functions are objects too and can have properties.

just do this

```
Sleep.moodAfterAwake =  ["bla","bla","bla"]
```